Is closing the rows using defer dangerous?
I found the code (code link) and use this code for my application.
Below is the part of the code that I want to share
query := "SELECT 1"
    rows, err := db.Query(query) // no cancel is allowed
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("failed to run a query. %v, err: %v", query, err)
    }
    defer rows.Close()

As you can see, they use the defer rows.Close() to close the rows.
Most cases, it won't be problem.
However, when I running my application using the code below, sometimes I got panic at the defer rows.close(). Therefore I suspect that while closing the rows, the rows is nil or something problem exists.
func getResultString(rows *sql.Rows) (*string, error) {
    defer rows.Close()

    var result string
    if rows.Next() {
        if err := rows.Scan(&result); err != nil {
            return nil, fmt.Errorf("scan err, %v", err)
        } else {
            return &result, nil
        }
    }
    return nil, fmt.Errorf("query err, %v", rows.Err())
}

Therefore I tried to change the code as below since it is more safe and best practice explained on the website.
func getResultString(rows *sql.Rows) (*string, error) {
    defer func() {
        err := rows.Close()
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("Error closing rows:", err)
        }
    }()

    var result string
    if rows.Next() {
        if err := rows.Scan(&result); err != nil {
            return nil, fmt.Errorf("scan err, %v", err)
        } else {
            return &result, nil
        }
    }
    return nil, fmt.Errorf("query err, %v", rows.Err())
}

Is my trial recommended way or right thing to do? Also, any help will be appreciated.
Thanks,

The problem is not "Is closing the rows using defer dangerous?" it is not. The problem is that you call a method on a nil rows and this is not "dangerous", this is plain wrong. Your second code is just utterly complex.

@Volker why you think the second code is complex? I appreciate it if you could more explain for your reason.

The error "handling" in defer is strange, closing the sql.Rows seems wrong, error handling is strange, return values are strange. No idea how to use that function correctly.

Note that in your second example err := will create a new local variable. I can understand this might be an actual intent, so handling of that error is turned into warning. If yes, then, well, I'd consider that to be a case of overengeneering–basically because I'd expect that a failed anything would preclude subsequent operations from completing successfully (IOW, once Close on an instance of sql.Rows fails, I'd not expect a second call to rows.Scan to succeed).

All-in-all, I'd say the following. Error handing in defer is not bad/wrong per se but it has two downsides:

It creates convoluted code resembling try/catch in other mainstream PLs — something Go designers excplicitly strived to avoid. I say "convoluted" because it removes the error handling from the point the error happened at.
Of course, as always, there are trade-offs to make; sometimes defer fits just right — especially where you expect panics.
defer-red code runs right before the function is about to return. This means any resources which are to be freed by calls performed in the deferred functions are not freed until the functon ends. For small functions performing one or a very few tasks that may be OK, but consider what happens if performing a Query* using your database/sql driver uses up some resource at the server and/or in the driver; you might end up in a situation when you can perform only N such requests in a single function, and N+1th will fail.

In your rather simple example using defer is OK but I'd rewrite it into something like this:
func getResultString(rows *sql.Rows) (res string, err error) {
    defer func() {
        closeErr := rows.Close()
        if closeErr != nil && err == nil {
            err = closeErr
        }
    }()

    if rows.Next() {
        err = rows.Scan(&res)
    } else {
        err = rows.Err()
    }
    
    return
}

And here we see that ditching defer makes the simple example simpler:
func getResultString(rows *sql.Rows) (res string, err error) {
    if !rows.Next() {
        return "", rows.Err()
    }

    errs := []error{rows.Scan(&res), rows.Close()}
    for _, err = range errs {
        if err != nil {
            break
        }
    }
    
    return
}

